# React update url base on action

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new to ReactJS. I have a problem with React Router v4 and need some advice from you guys. 
In my application (React + Redux), I'm configuring my route:

```
/app/:appId/detail
/app/:appId/config/:store
/app/:appId/gifts
```

And render 2 components at the same time. A **select** component (allow change *appId*) and a main component (showing data).

Suppose that I'm in */app/1/detail* with appId is 1 and showing a detail from application 1. When I press change application to 2, I want to change my url like */app/2/detail* and change data to application 2 by the time. (means matching :appId to 2)

I know that I can dispatch an action with Redux then **DetailComponent** (or **ConfigComponent**/**GiftsComponent**) can catch it and change manual from inside component (every component) by using **history.push or history.replace**. My application have a lot of components, manual handling can increase complexity in my app, so it is not a good way to resolve it.

Help me if having any solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If your problem is changing url, you need to use `<Link/>` component comes with the react-router. To load the data when the url changes, you should use React `componentWillReceiveProps()` life cycle method.

Comment: Hi @TharakaWijebandara, sorry if my question confused you. <Link/> is for clickable element. If I change the appId, no matter what url currently I have, it should update to match /app/:appId/[xyz]

Answer (score 6):

So you mentioned that

> A select component (allow change appId) and a main component (showing
>   data).

And also state that you are worried about the following:

> My application have a lot of components, manual handling can increase
>   complexity in my app, so it is not a good way to resolve it.

So maybe you should go with wrapping this select component with `withRouter` HOC first as it is already mentioned, if this select component is used more than once.

Wrapping would allow you to access the following props =>

```
props: { match, location, history }
```

`match` object also contains `params` and `url`. Url stores the value of current path. In your case it basically is `/app/1/detail`. Params stores the parameters that the route has. In your case params would be the following  `params { appId: 1 }` Having access to these props would allow you to implement and maintain routing logic inside of a single component.

So if you use a dropdown menu you can do the following

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

const SelectComponent = ({match: {params, url}}) => (
  <div>
    dropDownItems.map(item => 
       <Link 
        key={item.id // or simply item.appId}
        to={url.replace(`${params.appId}`, `item.appId`)
       >
        Change application to {item.appId}
      </Link>
    </div>
)

export default withRouter(SelectComponent)
```

Since `params.appId` corresponds to '1' and I assume that there won't be any parameter that equals to the value of  `appId`, `url.replace(...)` 
would basically replace the value of former `appId` with the new value in the url.

So any change should redirect you to the new route with the updated `appId`

If you use buttons you can also use `<Link />` to wrap your button I guess, but you could also use `history.push` method as an `onClick` event to handle the redirection.

Comment: Thank @Cagri Yardimci very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is not clear, it seems you want to change the current url programmatically with react-router.

For this you will need the [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC from react-router. With it you can do something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

const ExampleComponent = (props) => {

  const goToNextId = () => {
    props.history.push(`/app/${props.match.params.appId + 1}/detail`);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={goToNextId}>Next Id</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ExampleComponent.propTypes = {
  history: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withRouter(ExampleComponent);
```