# react-router v4 - How to change only one part of the URL path and leave the rest untouched?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have a React - Redux - React Router v4 application in which the URL looks something like this:

```
www.mysite.com/:accountName/brands/:brandId/something
www.mysite.com/:accountName/brands/:brandId/somethingElse
```

An actual example would be:

**www.mysite.com/sears/brands/levis/jobs**

In my global navigation menu, I have a **Brand Select** dropdown menu where I can switch the selected brand via. **brandId**. The idea is to keep the rest of the URL untouched and just change the **brandId** param.

So when the new brand URL is clicked, the updated URL should be:
**www.mysite.com/sears/brands/wrangler/jobs**

One approach I thought of was to use a RegEx to replace the path, but that seems like an imperative approach.

Is there a native way in React Router v4 to achieve this?

Comment: build Parent react component and initialize state with those params and have render method with ROUTE component binded as follows.

"<Route path=`/:${this.state.accountName}/brands/:${this.state.brandId}/something` component={something} />"

Comment: I think there's been an answer for the question you are asking here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141025/react-update-url-base-on-action, basically you can just replace the current params in the url with a new one.